# OpenGL freezes and turns off blender

Tags: interface, opengl

I've encountered this behavior several times that blender put random black and white points on the blender window then a message box appears and says "Too many errors occurred. Application must close now"

[image: Screenshot 001]

I know that my environment is a bit old but it supports OpenGL 3.4

```
Lenovo ThinkPad T410
Intel Core i5 540M
Nvidia NVS3100 (this supports OpenGL 3.4)
8GB RAM
180GB SSD
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating your graphics card driver would be great. I did and I can use blender with no problems.

Comment: Already the latest version

Comment: Upgrading is great if it wasn't a llaptop